# add display.none to a listview on page_load

Tags: .net, asp.net, listview

I have a listview and want to change its style to  display:none on pageload event.
I don't want to set visible=false because I want the element available to javascript code on client side. I am trying this one but with no luck. The div is rendered and is visible.

```
CategoriesDataList.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display,"none");
```

The html is:

```
<asp:ListView ID="CategoriesDataList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlCategories"
    OnItemDataBound="CategoriesDataList_Databound" ItemPlaceholderID="categoriesPlaceh">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div id="questionnaire"> ... 
          <asp:PlaceHolder ID="categoriesPlaceh" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder> 
       ...</div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate> ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I did it by adding a runat="server" to the div inside the LayoutTemplate and then using FindControl in code behind to change its style. I saw that actually this was the first element that was rendered and not a div with the listview id as I was initially expecting

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just add the `style="display:none;"` to the server tag?  This generally works for me, the server tags normally just convert the extra attributes across.

`<asp:ListView ID="MyListView" runat="Server" style="display:none;" />`

Comment: I initially want it to be visible, then on button_click reload the page and hide it and after that use some javascript to display it again